# Why doesn't Control.Monad contain a << function?

Tags: haskell, monads

Does anyone know why [Control.Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html) doesn't contain a function `<<`?

What I mean specifically is

```
(<<) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m a
(<<) = flip (>>)
```

It’s easy enough to implement but I don't see why `<<` isn't included given that `>>` is included and that `>>=` has `=<<` and `>=>` has `<=<`.

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, `(<*)` is not `flip (>>)`. They have the same types, but they sequence effects in the opposite direction.

Comment: Hard to say, but I'd guess that `f =<< x` is sometimes preferred to `x >>= f` because the standard application notation is `f x`, not `x f`. Instead, with `a >> b` we do not apply the result of `a` to `b` and the "natural" left-to-right order for sequencing effects is already used, so there's little need for `<<`.

Comment: @Carl Ah yes I see that now, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: chi's suggestion makes sense, but generally I wouldn't try too much too interpret why such and such operator is or is not contained in a module. It is clearly not feasible that _every_ operator that could potentially be useful be included in the base library. There already are quite many (arguably _too_ many), and reasons why some operator is included can include anything between “I needed this particular operator in some application, and it seems general enough to put in `base`” and “probably good to have that operator, because maths/symmetry” and “hey, look what a cute signature this has”.